# Why is some of my JSON data not showing in my table view?

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, count

In one screen I have two table views, so I have written code like this. If I use one table view then I get the whole data, but with two table views I have this issue.

**code:** Here `skillsTableView` is not showing the entire JSON data. For testing purposes I have taken `skillsArray`. If I print this here I get all of the data.

But in my `skillsTableView`, I don't get the total data. I can't use `skillsArray` to count because I need every skill's corresponding id too.

Why am I not getting the whole JSON data in my `skillsTableView`?

```swift
private var skillsMasterData = SkillsMasterModel(dictionary: NSDictionary()) {
    didSet {
        skillsArray = skillsMasterData?.result?.skills?.compactMap { $0.skill }
        print("skills array \(skillsArray)")
        skillsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == tableView {
        return langCellArray.count
    } else {
        return skillsMasterData?.result?.skills?.count ?? 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EditLangTableVIewCell", for: indexPath) as! EditLangTableVIewCell
        let item = langCellArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.langLbl.text = item.name
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SkillsTableVIewCell", for: indexPath) as! SkillsTableVIewCell
        
        let item = skillsMasterData?.result?.skills?[indexPath.row]
        cell.skillsLabel.text = item?.skill
        let id = skillsMasterData?.result?.skills?[indexPath.row].id ?? 0
        
        if arrSelectedRows.contains(id) {
            cell.chkImage.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
        } else {
            cell.chkImage.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: You will save yourself some troubles with optionals if you remove them early, e.g. `let skills = skillsMasterData?.result?.skills ?? []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `numberOfRowsInSection` method has a mistake when checking the table view.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView === self.tableView { // <-- Add self. and use ===
        return langCellArray.count
    } else {
        return skillsMasterData?.result?.skills?.count ?? 0
    }
}
```

The mistake meant that `if tableView == tableView` was always true and you returned `langCellArray.count` for both table views.

It's also better to use `===` than `==` when comparing object references since in a case like this you want to see if they are the same instances. You are not trying to compare if two object have the same attributes.

Comment: Also, there should be `===`. In the end both `==` and `===` will do the same for `UITableView`, however we want to compare references here.

Comment: ye, i did that in `cellForRowAt ` but i forgot in `numberOfRowsInSection` my bad, thank you, saved my time

Comment: @Sulthan Good catch. I do that in my own code but overlooked it here. Updated the answer a bit.